# Avoid printing of dots

Tags: python, pytest

I run pytest with option `-q`.

Unfortunately this prints out a lot of dots. Example:

```
...................................................................................s...............s...................................ssssss..................................................................................................................................s..............s.........................s..............................................................................................................F....s.s............s.....................s...........................................................................................................................
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________ TestFoo.test_bar _____________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (cut)
```

Is there a way to avoid this long list of dots and "s" characters?

**Update**

There is a valid answer. But somehow it is too long for me. I use this workaround now:I added this to the script which calls pytest: `pytest -q | perl -pe 's/^[.sxFE]{20,}$//g'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verbosity options can't turn off the test outcome printing. However, `pytest` can be customized in many ways, including the outcome printing. To change this, you would override the [`pytest_report_teststatus`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_report_teststatus) hook.

#### turn off short letters

Create a file `conftest.py` with the following content:

```python
import pytest

def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    category, short, verbose = '', '', ''
    if hasattr(report, 'wasxfail'):
        if report.skipped:
            category = 'xfailed'
            verbose = 'xfail'
        elif report.passed:
            category = 'xpassed'
            verbose = ('XPASS', {'yellow': True})
        return (category, short, verbose)
    elif report.when in ('setup', 'teardown'):
        if report.failed:
            category = 'error'
            verbose = 'ERROR'
        elif report.skipped:
            category = 'skipped'
            verbose = 'SKIPPED'
        return (category, short, verbose)
    category = report.outcome
    verbose = category.upper()
    return (category, short, verbose)
```

Now running the tests will not print any short outcome letters (`.sxFE`). The code is a bit verbose, but handles all the standard outcomes defined in the framework.

#### turn off verbose outcomes

When running in verbose mode, `pytest` prints the outcome along with the test case name:

```
$ pytest -sv
=================================== test session starts ===================================
...
test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs FAILED
test_spam.py::test_bacon SKIPPED
test_spam.py::test_foo xfail
...
```

If you remove the lines setting `verbose` from the above hook impl (leaving it set to an empty string), `pytest` will also stop printing outcomes in verbose mode:

```python
import pytest

def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    category, short, verbose = '', '', ''
    if hasattr(report, 'wasxfail'):
        if report.skipped:
            category = 'xfailed'
        elif report.passed:
            category = 'xpassed'
        return (category, short, verbose)
    elif report.when in ('setup', 'teardown'):
        if report.failed:
            category = 'error'
        elif report.skipped:
            category = 'skipped'
        return (category, short, verbose)
    category = report.outcome
    return (category, short, verbose)
```

```
$ pytest -sv
=================================== test session starts ===================================
...
test_spam.py::test_spam
test_spam.py::test_eggs
test_spam.py::test_bacon
test_spam.py::test_foo
...
```

#### introducing custom reporting mode via command line switch

The below example will turn off printing both short and verbose outcomes when `--silent` flag is passed from command line:

```python
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--silent', action='store_true', default=False)


def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    category, short, verbose = '', '', ''
    if not config.getoption('--silent'):
        return None

    if hasattr(report, 'wasxfail'):
        if report.skipped:
            category = 'xfailed'
        elif report.passed:
            category = 'xpassed'
        return (category, short, verbose)
    elif report.when in ('setup', 'teardown'):
        if report.failed:
            category = 'error'
        elif report.skipped:
            category = 'skipped'
        return (category, short, verbose)
    category = report.outcome
    return (category, short, verbose)
```

Comment: Apparently, the global config object in Pytest has been deprecated, and at least with 6.2, the code above no longer runs (`AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'config'`). Would be great if someone could modernize this code.

Comment: @JeffWright `pytest_report_teststatus` now also accepts the config object as argument, so the update is easy - check out the updated snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using my plugin [`pytest-custom-report`](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-custom-report) you can easily suppress those dots by using an empty-string marker for the report.

```
pip install pytest-custom-report
pytest -q --report-passed=""
```