# Making PYTEST quieter when run from PYCHARM

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

UPDATE: The messages shown below are NOT controlled by pytest various "-q" quiet options.  They are coming from the TeamCity plugin...
see my answer below.

ORIGINAL: I have read the existing stack overflow answers for silencing pytest, but none tell how to silence the HUGE number of redundant "test passing" messages I am getting.  I have so many, my errors get lost scrolling off the page.  (Since this is in pycharm, I can add args, but I do not control the command line.)

help!

For clarity, I want to remove these messages:
(neither --silent, nor -q seem to work)

```
test_lang.py::TestParsing::test_parsing PASSED                           [  2%]
test_lang.py::TestParsing::test_xxx PASSED                               [  3%]
test_mixin.py::TestHeadSettable::test_headsettable PASSED                [  4%]
test_mixin.py::TestPathy::test_tree_null_creation PASSED
```

...

```
test_uf.py::TestListyStructure::test_extend[UnitList] PASSED             [ 96%]
test_uf.py::TestListyStructure::test_extend[UnitListWrapper] PASSED      [ 97%]
test_uf.py::TestListyStructure::test_slice[UnitList] PASSED              [ 98%]
test_uf.py::TestListyStructure::test_slice[UnitListWrapper] PASSED       [ 99%]
test_uf.py::TestUnitMisc::test_main PASSED                               [100%]

============================= 101 passed in 0.49s ==============================
```

Comment: What commands are you running to execute your tests?

Comment: If you run it from command line on Linux OS, you can use: `<your_command> >/dev/null`. In this case the STDOUT will be redirected to `/dev/null` so if there is an error during running test, you will see it. If you want to suppress tatally the output of `pytest`, you can use: ` <your_command> >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: `pytest -p no:terminal` will suppress any output, `pytest -qqq` will suppress everything but the dot line. If you want to suppress the dot printing, you'll need to customize `pytest` internals; check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383343/2650249) for a working example.

Comment: If `pytest -q` still prints a line for each test (like `test_uf.py::TestUnitMisc::test_main PASSED  [100%]`), then you have verbose flags stored in `pytest.ini` or `setup.cfg` in the `addopts` config line; remove them first so `-qqq` is not negated by the `-v` flag.

Comment: My oversight!  I am running this from pycharm, and pycharm has created its own runner python script that I have no control over (I have no pytest config files)

Comment: Found!  PyCharm's runner script is silently jamming a plugin call TeamCity into pytest.  This plugin is the issue!  I will write up the fix.  It involves editing their internal runner script (YUCK!) . Not sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(see bottom for details for latest versions of PyCharm)

SOLUTION FOR PYCHARM 2018  Pycharm is silently installing a pytest plugin called TeamCity.  It needs this plugin to track which tests succeed or fail.  You can disable this loading of this plugin by editing the Pycharm runner script.  (Yuck!)

On a Mac this file is located at:
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py

Add the line as shown below to disable the loading of TeamCity:

```
...
jb_doc_args("pytest", args)
# We need to preparse numprocesses because user may set it using ini file
plugins_to_load = []    # <--- ADD THIS LINE TO AVOID TEAMCITY PLUGIN
config_result = real_prepare_config(args, plugins_to_load)
...
```

```
UPDATE FOR 2019.3 and later.
On a Mac this file is located at: /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py


    ...
    jb_doc_args("pytest", args)
    plugins_to_load = []    # ADDED THIS LINE TO AVOID EXTRA PYTEST PRINTING
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Linux:**

You can use: `<your_command> >/dev/null`. In this case the STDOUT will be redirected to `/dev/null`. It means if there is an error (STDERR) during running test, you will see it. If you want to suppress totally the output of `pytest`, you can use: `<your_command> >/dev/null 2>&1`. In this case the STDOUT and STDERR will be redirected to `/dev/null`

**Example:**

```
py.test test.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

---

**Windows:**

The situation is very similar in case of Windows OS. Only you can use `NUL` insted of `/dev/null`.

**Example:**

```
py.test test.py 2>&1 >NUL
```