# How to print only the summary with pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I would like pytest to only print the summary when running my tests. I am using the the -s flag so other output is passed through. Even with --quiet it prints the little green dots (in case of success). I would like to suppress those. It would be also good to have explicit control over what's printed after tests so that I can separate the outputs with whitespace or something, but this is a different question.

I am doing this so that I can check the output of my CLI.

Comment: Does [pytest-custom-report](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-custom-report) plugin help you at all?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but seems quite unideal overall.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/53374551/2650249

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for your guidance. Check out my dope solution. Btw, I've been admiring your hair for almost a decade.

Comment: @MatrixTheatrics I don't get it, in what way does `pytest -q --report-passed="" -s` not already do what you wanted here? In your "dope solution" that is just using the same hook which the plugin already uses, but it's done in an ugly and non-generic way.

Comment: @wim You are mostly right. All the poo icons and the other noise, plus the fact that it's an external plugin, made me look in another direction. Names of the test files are still printed though. Initially I didn't want to be specific what happens if it passes/fails/etc., but just overall to suppress output. Still, if you gave what you just wrote as an answer I'd have accepted it and not implement my "dope" solution most likely.

Overall my solution's implementation might not be the most beautiful, the end result however most definitely is.

Comment: @MatrixTheatrics The names of test files are not printed. Perhaps you didn't pass the `-q` option if you're still seeing test file names? Not sure why it's a problem that it's an "external" plugin, when pytest itself is an external project in the first place.  *(disclaimer: I am on pytest-dev organization)*

Comment: @wim You're right again, I stopped passing -q after realizing the dots won't go away and them I'd just forgotten about it. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it since that's more relevant to the posed question compared to mine. Regarding the pluginness, it's fine, but still, it's an additional SOUP element from my perspective so it was just that bit less attractive. And thanks for your input.

Comment: @MatrixTheatrics okay, it is posted as answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my plugin [`pytest-custom-report`](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-custom-report) you can customize all the glyphs used for report characters. Using an empty string would effectively hide them.

```
pytest -q --report-passed="" -s
```

Passing `-q` to pytest additionally hides the test filenames.

Comment: ‘--report-passed’ doesn’t seem to be available any more (I’m on version 7.2.0).

Comment: @CarlWinbäck Still working fine on 7.2.0, I just checked. Have you installed the plugin that is mentioned in the answer? The option is only available with the plugin installed.

Comment: Ah. Excuse me. Sloppy reading on my part. I simply need to install the plugin then. Thank you @wim!

Answer (score 1):

[hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646756/how-to-print-only-the-summary-with-pytest#comment114319081_64646756) set me in the right direction. By setting `short` str, you can customize what's output instead of dots; forwarding the rest of the elements of the tuple while leaving this at an empty string should suffice. I even did some... see for yourself. Using --verbose is not recommended. Could remove more parts, ones that deal with failure cases, but didn't care about that now.

[A nice picture of the output.](https://pasteboard.co/JyCjgtL.png) (no rep yet to post it here)

```
from _pytest.reports import CollectReport, TestReport, Config
from typing import Tuple, Union, Mapping
import py

def pytest_report_teststatus(report: Union[CollectReport, TestReport], config: Config, files_set=set()) \
        -> Tuple[str, str, Union[str, Mapping[str, bool]]]:
    def get_line_delim():
        n = py.io.TerminalWriter().fullwidth // 3
        return f'\n{"*  "*n}\n'
    category, short, verbose = '', '', ''
    if hasattr(report, 'wasxfail'):
        if report.skipped:
            category = 'xfailed'
            verbose = 'xfail'
        elif report.passed:
            category = 'xpassed'
            verbose = ('XPASS', {'yellow': True})
        return (category, short, verbose)
    elif report.when in ('setup', 'teardown'):
        if report.failed:
            category = 'error'
            verbose = 'ERROR'
        elif report.skipped:
            category = 'skipped'
            verbose = 'SKIPPED'
        elif report.when == 'setup' and report.location[0] not in files_set:
            files_set.add(report.location[0]) # needed so that the first test for each file can start out clean
            return (category, get_line_delim(), (verbose, {'red': True}))
        return (category, short, verbose)
    category = report.outcome
    verbose = category.upper()
    return (category, get_line_delim(), (verbose, {'red': True}))
```